# DDNS and home server

Tags: webserver, ddns

I am looking to get my homeserver (either MAC OSx 10.9 server or Ubuntu) to been seen from the web, I have looked into DDNS but cannot find one which is straightforward, both machines are VM's running on ESXI and will have access to the internet.

I already own a few domains and can set up subdomains if need be
I can access the DNS records on my Plesk panel from my web host
My home broadband uses a dynamic IP (this is my problem)
I want to be able to acces my files when out and about

can anyone recommend or put me on the right path please

Answer (score 0):

I've used http://www.no-ip.org in the past. You can install their Dynamic DNS Update Client software that detects when the IP changes in order to change the DNS registries.